# Does creating a root site collection affect existent managed path site collections?

Tags: 2013, site-creation

In our existent sharepoint 2013 web we only have site collections in the default managed path http://servername/sites/collectionname. Is it safe to create a root site collection without affecting the existent collections, such as search or user permissions?

The only reason we want a root site is to use alias name (CNAME) to connect, and then redirect to one of the other collections.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's fine to create a root site collection. In fact in the past I've come across scenarios where not having a root site collection actually caused issues (though I can't remember off the top of my head what those issues were).

Answer (score 0):

Simple HTTP Redirect in IIS should do the trick without having to add root site collection and do client side redirect.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should create the Root Level Site collection, without root level Site collection SharePoint will have tons of Issue. Couple of these are

- MMS will have issue
- MySite will not work properly
- many Urls reside under the root site level( _layouts folder) will be broken

Couple of reference: [Link 1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mpriem/archive/2012/11/07/always-have-a-root-site-collection.aspx) , [Link 2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2559901)

It is safe to create and you should do it.